# Trying to type props used in filter category function in React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hey I'm trying to create an interface ICategories to my filter categories function in React with Typescript.  I'm not sure what to type the props in categoryPage.tsx, also fix the other typing errors. Will write error next to the code. Can someone help?

Here is **categoryPage.tsx**

```
export const CategoryPage = ({ categories, filterCategory, setFilterCategory }: ICategories) => {
  const onChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => { // "Binding element 'input' implicitly has an 'any' type."
    if(input.checked) {
        const state = [...filterCategory, input.value];
        setFilterCategory(state)
    } else {
        const state = filterCategory.filter((val) => val !== input.value) // Parameter 'val' implicitly has an 'any' type"
        setFilterCategory(state)
    }
  }
    return (
    <div>
        <h1>Filter By Category</h1>
        <div>
            {categories.map((category: string) => {
                <div key={category}>
                    <input 
                        type="checkbox"
                        value={category}
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                    <p>{category}</p>
                </div>
            })}
        </div>
        <Categories />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**categoryInterface.ts**:

```
export interface ICategories {
    categories: 
    filterCategory: 
    setFilterCategory: 
}
```

And lastly **App.tsx**:

```
function App() {
  const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useState<IProductItem[]>([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filterCategory, setFilterCategory] = useState([]);
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({}) // I need to type the useState here
  const AllProductsContextValue: IAllProductsContext = {
    allProducts: allProducts
  }

  // Fetches all products from /products
  const fetchAllProducts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`/products/?search=${search}&category=${filterCategory.toString()}`);
    setAllProducts(response.data);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllProducts();
  }, [search, filterCategory]);

  return (
    <AllProductsContext.Provider value={AllProductsContextValue}>
      <ShoppingCartProvider>
        <Container className="mb-4">
          <Router>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/categories' 
                element={<CategoryPage 
                    filterCategory={filterCategory} 
                    categories={obj.categories ? obj.categories : []} 
                    setFilterCategory={(category) => setFilterCategory(category)} // Parameter 'category' implicitly has an 'any' type.
                    />} 
                />
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        </Container>
      </ShoppingCartProvider>
    </AllProductsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` installed.

```
npm i @types/react --save-dev
npm i @types/react-dom --save-dev
```

---

Hovering over the `onChange` HTML property shows the following intellisense:

```
(property) InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>.onChange?: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>
```

You can use that type for your callback function.

```
import { ChangeEventHandler } from 'react';
```

```
const onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {...}
```

Then tsc can infer `currentTarget` is an `HTMLInputElement`.

---

Hovering over `useState` reveals it is a generic function.

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>]
```

```
// default value will also need to match type
const [obj, setObj] = useState<YourTypeHere>({})
```

---

Retyping a parameter for `setFilterCategory` shouldn't be necessary

```
setFilterCategory={setFilterCategory}
```

However you should type `useState` as mentioned above

```
const [filterCategory, setFilterCategory] = useState<YourTypeHere[]>([]);
```